# Синхронный timeout / interval

Tags: setinterval, settimeout

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть функция motionEnemy, нужно сделать так, чтобы последующий код после этой функции не совершался, пока она активна.

```
motionEnemy = function () {
        if ( whichSide === 'r') {
            if ( (frameWidth / 2) != enemyDistance ) {
                enemy.css({marginRight: enemyDistance + 'px'});
                enemyDistance += STEP_LENGHT;
                setTimeout(motionEnemy,__self.GAME_TICK);
            }
        } else {
            if ( (frameWidth / 2) != enemyDistance ) {
                enemy.css({marginLeft: enemyDistance + 'px'});
                enemyDistance += STEP_LENGHT;
                setTimeout(motionEnemy, __self.GAME_TICK);
            }
        }
    };
    setTimeout(motionEnemy(),__self.GAME_TICK);
    console.log('ФУНКЦИЯ ЗАВЕРШИЛАСЬ');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить флаг активности движения и callback на завершение

```js
isMoveActive = false; // флаг активности
onMoveDone = false; // обработчик завершения движения
motionEnemy = function () {
    if ( (frameWidth / 2) != enemyDistance ) {
        var res;
        if ( whichSide === 'r') {
            res = {marginRight: enemyDistance + 'px'};
        } else {
            res = {marginLeft: enemyDistance + 'px'};
        }
        enemy.css(res);
        enemyDistance += STEP_LENGHT;
        setTimeout(motionEnemy,__self.GAME_TICK);
    }
    else {
        // сброс флага и запуск callback
        isMoveActive = false;
        if (typeof onMoveDone == 'function') {
            onMoveDone();
        }
    }
};
startMove = function() {
    if (!isMoveActive) {
        // установка флага и запуск функции
        isMoveActive = true;
        setTimeout(motionEnemy,__self.GAME_TICK);
    }
};
onMoveDone = function() {
    console.log('ФУНКЦИЯ ЗАВЕРШИЛАСЬ');
};
startMove();
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста где можно прочитать подробнее, как это работает. я не понимаю, как интерпретатор выполняет этот код.

Comment: Советую прочитать серию статей ["Выразительный JavaScript"](https://habrahabr.ru/post/240219/)